# Meteor: How to check if template instance is still alive?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to auto redirect after 10 sec to the next screen.
But only if the user hasn't left the page already.
How do I test in the callback method if the template still exists (That "alive" var in the code below)?

My Coffeescript:

```
Template.handBackDevice.onRendered(->    
  delay 10000, ->
        if alive
            Router.go('/dropOff/confirmDropOff')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your `alive` flag outside of your Template function, in the same file, as a [reactive variable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) or inside a [reactive dictionary](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) (or alternatively as a Session variable) like this (reactive variable case):

```
var isAlive = new ReactiveVar(false);
```

And set it to `true` once your template is rendered

```
Template.name.onRendered = function(){
  isAlive.set(true);
  //add your delayed function
}
```

Hook on the template `destroyed` function and update the `alive` flag there:

```
Template.handBackDevice.onDestroyed = function(){ 
   isAlive.set(false)
};
```

You can then simply check on it in your delayed function using

```
if (isAlive.get()){
//do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there no easier way? Like with a this reference?

Comment: not that I know of. I doesn't seem too complicated to me

Comment: I just re-read your comment. Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but you can attach the reactive var to your template when declaring it: `this.isAlive = new ReactiveVar(false);`